# Load different layout in activity based on button clicked from fragment

Tags: android

I have 2 buttons in a fragment. I want to send intent to Activity from fragment and load a layout based on the button clicked. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Put Some code What you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution to this. Passing a string (using putExtra) to help decide which layout to be loaded.

Fragment Code:

```
Button button1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.id_button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ScrollingDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(ScrollingDetailsActivity.EXTRA_DATA,"Button1_pressed");
            (getActivity()).startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    Button button2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.id_button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ScrollingDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(ScrollingDetailsActivity.EXTRA_DATA,"Button2_pressed");
            (getActivity()).startActivity(intent);
```

Activity Code:

```
    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String data = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_DATA);

    if (data.equals("button1_pressed"))
    setContentView(R.layout.scrolling_details_button1);

    if (data.equals("button2_pressed"))
        setContentView(R.layout.scrolling_details_button2);
```

Thanks!!